# SQL Select n random groups and return all records

Tags: sql, postgresql, random

I can't seem to find a solution to this exact question, without chaining together 2 or more queries together via pandas manipulation. (I had previously been attempting a random sampling in postgresql in the vein of `cur.execute("select distinct group from data where random() < {0}".format(rand_coef))`, but I was unable to combine the resulting array into a single query, nor specify the exact n value.)

A hypothetical dataset and query is as follows:

Say I want n = 3 random groups from the following data.

```
id, group, value
1,a,23
1,a,3
1,b,2
1,a,432
1,b,123
1,d,23
1,d,11
1,c,23
1,c,234
1,a,223
1,c,32
```

An example result of a query would be n=3 random groups (i.e. b,c,d):

```
id, group, value
1,b,2
1,b,123
1,d,23
1,d,11
1,c,23
1,c,234
1,c,32
```

How might this work?

Comment: Can you explain your current solution and why two or more queries won't work for you?

Comment: I had previously been attempting a random sampling in postgresql in the vein of `cur.execute("select distinct group from data where random() < {0}".format(rand_coef))`, but I was unable to combine the resulting array into a single query, nor specify the exact n value.

Answer (score 2):

One method would be:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select group
      from t
      group by group
      order by random()
      limit 3
     ) g
    on t.group = g.group;
```

Note that `group` is a really bad name for a column, because it is a SQL keyword.

Comment: I agree with everything you posted, but doesn't the sub-query negate the OP's requirement: "I can't seem to find a solution to this exact answer, without chaining together 2 or more queries together."??

Comment: `group` is just an example column name, but I appreciate the tip.